# how to create Mschart in VB6?

Tags: database, ms-access, vb6

How can i retrieve data from database and display in chart format using MSChart in visual basic6.(Not in VB .NET).??? pls pls.... send me d answer...

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the following example code:
[Display Data on a Chart Using MSChart control: Demo](http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=1538).
It's compatible with VB5 and 6

There is a nice tutorial on handling the difficulties (and getting started) with the chart control in VB6 here: [Microsoft Chart - A How To Guide For Handling The VB 6 Charting Beast](http://www.vb123.com/toolshed/99_vbchart/vbchart1.htm)

Comment: If you deem an answer worthy of being the answer you looked for - vote it up with the arrow buttons next to the answer and/or accept it with the checkmark next to it.